# Manually compile SASS to CSS via C# Action for Customizable Frontend Layouts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sass

I try to build a Webfrontend that is customizable by my users.

My users do not have any webDev skills and internally I work with SCSS files 
so I got the idea to give them my sass-variables for customization.

(You may have seen something like this before in themeRollers of some reputable CSS-Frameworks.)

So my workflow is something like this:

1. Users get the variables of my SASS to edit
2. they post these Variables to an Controller Action
3. **MAGIC**: my .SCSS-file becomes a .CSS-file
4. I save the .CSS file to provide it for a later webrequest

I need your help, because I don't know how Step 3 could look like.
Maybe you have already implemented this or you have a useful thought.

I'm very grateful for any suggestion

Answer (score 24, accepted):

So I found a way to do the magic by using [NSass](http://www.nuget.org/packages/NSass.Core/).
I have to test if/how it supports @imports but it seems to be the right direction for that problem.

Here's a little Snippet using NSass

```
string scss = "button.button{background-color: #fff; &:hover{opacity: 0.5;}}"
var compiler = new SassCompiler();
string compiled = compiler.Compile(source: scss, outputStyle: OutputStyle.Compressed, sourceComments: false); //returns "button.button {background-color:#ffffff;}button.button:hover {opacity:0.5;}"
```

Comment: +1 for providing an actual example of how to use NSass

Comment: @CelsiusF Did you try imports in NSASS? I had error that files imported to my main file are not found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693530/compiling-scss-files-in-action?noredirect=1#comment49498192_30693530

Comment: @celsiusF I tried 
string compiled = compiler.CompileFile(@"C:\dev\project...", OutputStyle.Compressed, false);
but my .scss file didn't re-compile

Comment: I get an error saying The type initializer for 'NSass.SassCompiler' threw an exception. when i use that code? I have installed the NSass from nuget package manager. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You can setup a plugin called web developer tools inside of your visual studio. Each time, that you update your less or sass file the vs will generate the files for you.

Is free

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361

And, if you wanna do this dynamically. You can add this nuget package for your project:

https://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/

Comment: Well I already use this plugin, but how can I let do this by a "service endpoint"? My users will only get my variables not my visual studio :/

Comment: I edited the post. This is a nugget package that allow you compile and run sass script in execution time. You can use the bundle if you are using ASP.NET MVC and do some magic.

Comment: I think you can extend some of the classes of this library. And try call your web service. Please, if the answer was util mark the question as done!